# Passing an associative array to a function within an procedure throws PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_t AS OBJECT
(
  c1 number,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION sort_key RETURN VARCHAR2
)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY num_t AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION sort_key RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN c1;
   END;
END;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE num_tab AS TABLE OF num_t
```

My package is defined as follows:

```
create or replace package test_package is

  type t_test is table of number index by binary_integer;
  test_empty_array t_test;

  procedure test_proc(cur_out out sys_refcursor);

  function test_fn(i_test in t_test) return num_tab;

end test_package;

create or replace package body test_package is

  procedure test_proc(cur_out out sys_refcursor) is
    i_test t_test := test_empty_array;
  begin
    open cur_out for
      select * from table(test_fn(i_test));

  end;

  function test_fn(i_test in t_test) return num_tab is
    v_results num_tab;
  begin
    for i in i_test.first .. i_test.last loop
      v_results.extend;
      v_results(i) := num_t(c1 => i_test(i));
    end loop;

    return v_results;
  end;

end test_package;
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following errors:

```
Error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
Line: 7
Text: select * from table(test_fn(i_test));

Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_FN'
Line: 7
Text: select * from table(test_fn(i_test));

Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TEST_PACKAGE"."TEST_FN": invalid identifier
Line: 7
Text: select * from table(test_fn(i_test));

Error: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line: 7
Text: select * from table(test_fn(i_test));
```

It looks like it should work to me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is normal and expected. functions used in SQL can only reference SQL datatypes (eg you'd get an error if you had a boolean datatype too).

you can hide it in the package:

```
create or replace package test_package is

  type t_test is table of number index by binary_integer;
  test_empty_array t_test;

  procedure test_proc(cur_out out sys_refcursor);

  function test_fn(i_test in t_test) return num_tab;

end test_package;
/
create or replace package body test_package is

  procedure test_proc(cur_out out sys_refcursor) is
    i_test t_test := test_empty_array;
    t_num  num_tab;
  begin
    t_num := test_fn(i_test);
    open cur_out for
      select * from table(t_num);

  end;

  function test_fn(i_test in t_test) return num_tab is
    v_results num_tab := num_tab();
  begin
    for i in 1..i_test.count loop
      v_results.extend;
      v_results(i) := num_t(c1 => i_test(i));
    end loop;

    return v_results;
  end;

end test_package;
/
```

i also tweaked

```
v_results num_tab := num_tab();
```

and

```
for 1..i_test.count loop
```

as first..last would fail in the case of a blank array (numeric error)

eg with some data:

```
SQL> create or replace package body test_package is
  2
  3    procedure test_proc(cur_out out sys_refcursor) is
  4      i_test t_test;
  5      t_num  num_tab;
  6    begin
  7      i_test(1) := 1;
  8      i_test(2) := 3;
  9      t_num := test_fn(i_test);
 10      open cur_out for
 11        select * from table(t_num);
 12
 13    end;
 14
 15    function test_fn(i_test in t_test) return num_tab is
 16      v_results num_tab := num_tab();
 17    begin
 18      for i in 1..i_test.count loop
 19        v_results.extend;
 20        v_results(i) := num_t(c1 => i_test(i));
 21      end loop;
 22
 23      return v_results;
 24    end;
 25
 26  end test_package;
 27  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec test_package.test_proc(:c)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

        C1
----------
         1
         3

SQL>
```